# how to add css to jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jsp

I want to add background color to popup i.e. custom background color.but i am unable to change the background color of the popup.please help me out for this.

```
$("#simpleConfirm").confirm();
$("#complexConfirm").confirm({
    title: "Delete confirmation",
    text: "This is very dangerous, you shouldn't do it! Are you really really sure?",
    confirm: function (button) {
        button.fadeOut(2000).fadeIn(2000);
        alert("You just confirmed.");
    },
    cancel: function (button) {
        button.fadeOut(2000).fadeIn(2000);
        alert("You aborted the operation.");
    },
    confirmButton: "Yes I am",
    cancelButton: "No"
});
$("#dataConfirm").confirm();
$("#manualTrigger").click(function () {
    $.confirm({
        text: "This is a confirmation dialog manually triggered! Please confirm:",
        confirm: function () {
            alert("You just confirmed.");
        },
        cancel: function () {
            alert("You cancelled.");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Did you try `.css()`? http://api.jquery.com/css/ It would helpful if you provided the HTML also.

Answer (score 0):

Like ryanpcmcquen said, .css("background-color" , "new color that you want") should work if your popup has an original background-color property.

```
<div></div>


div {
background-color: black;
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
}



$(document).ready(function(){
    $("div").css("background-color" , "green");
});
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rOaVam

See the above for an example.